# What is the right way to concate the term "Big Data" with other german words?

Tags: spelling, anglicism, hyphen

You can find the term Big Data in the german language dictionary [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Big_Data). So we can say it's a german word now.

As it is a German word, I can concatenate it with other german words. But how?

Usually, if the word is not a German word, I can concatenate it through the use of a hyphen.

E.g.: "Der Deep-Learning-Begriff"

So, should I write

> Big datakontext

or

> Big-Data-Kontext?

Comment: "Big Data-Kontext", without the first hyphen, should be the correct spelling

Comment: @Beta Das stimmt nicht. Siehe den in meiner Antwort verlinkten Duden-Eintrag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Definitive Answer

Only the latter one - "Big-Data-Kontext" - is correct, see http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/bindestrich#K26

## Speculation

I think the *reason* for the linked rule is disambiguation. Best way to explain what I mean seems to be by using parentheses to illustrate the relations raised by the different hyphenations:

```
"big Data-Kontext" - big [datakontext]

"Big-Data-Kontext" - [big-data]-kontext
```

Another example I came across the last days is

"latent profile analysis"

which denominates an analysis of latent profiles and not a latent analysis of profiles! Thus the correct german translation is "Latente-Profil-Analyse", while "latente Profil-Analyse" would mean exactly the latter one.

Comment: Bei (noch) ungebräuchlichen Fremdwörtern werden von vielen auch Anführungszeichen akzeptiert, während eingebürgerte Lehnwörter zur Zusammenschreibung neigen: _„Big Data“-Kontext_ vs. _Bigdata-Kontext_ oder sogar _Bigdatakontext_. Im konkreten Fall würde ich allerdings auch die volle Durchkoppelung mit zwei Bindestrichen bevorzugen.